# not found template when using Angular 2 in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I am using angular 2 in ASP.NET MVC.

This is the "other" component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'other-app',
    templateUrl: './app/other/other.component'
})
export class OtherComponent {
    name = "kianoush";
}
```

and this is my app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OtherComponent } from './other/other.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        OtherComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and this app.component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>My Name is {{name}}</h1>
    <other-app></other-app>`
})
export class AppComponent {

    name = "Kianoush";
}
```

This is folder of my project:

[image: Folders]

But when I run the project it show me error in console:

> http://localhost:xxxx/Home/app/other/other.component 404 not found

Here is the HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<base href="/">
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your `.html` file for `templateUrl` ?

Comment: @BabarBilal i try that but it not solve

Comment: what is `Home` in your URL what is in your `<base href>` tag in `index.html` regarding your folder structure there is no Home folder. Your base tag shoud be set with `/`.

Comment: @BabarBilal `
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
`

Comment: this is the root component I'm taking about `<base` tag is should be in your header

Comment: Bro just search `<base` this in your html page if it is not there add `<base href="/">` in your header

Comment: i have not `<base href="/">`

Comment: add it to your `<head>` portion

Comment: What should I write?

Comment: `<base href="/">`

Comment: i put `<base href="/">` in header but error still not solve

Comment: @BabarBilal i edit question .

Answer (score 0):

are your templates in wwwroot?

You cant just access any part of the filesystem, and this is by design. If you want a template made available simply by requesting a URL, put it in the correct place in wwwroot.

If you want to send back a template through MVC's controller system, you'd need to make sure that the route

> http://localhost:xxxx/Home/app/other/other.component

has an associated controller method handling it. This should be a view controller method that returns a View for your template.

Comment: its asp mvc 5 . how do this way?